# cell value from worksheets into one column in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro so that for each cell in a worksheet (range is the same for all worksheets) it will be listed in a column in an existing worksheet in a different range. I have the reading portion of the macro, I don't know how to list the each value from the worksheets in an existing worksheet:

```
Sub wstocolumn() 'Saves the excel print area to a PDF file

    Dim fp As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim intWS As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
    For intWS = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        With wb.Worksheets(intWS)
            Set rng = .Range("A1")
            Set Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A4:A10") = rng '<----- this is where I want each value_ _from the worksheets
        End With
    Next intWS
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrCells() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim arrCells(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        i = i + 1
        arrCells(i) = ws.Range("A1").Value
    Next ws

    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A4").Resize(i).Value = Application.Transpose(arrCells)

End Sub
```